# Fetching data from Javascript

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch

How can I get data from a server with no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' ?
I can get an Opaque answer only.

Problem is that I need to call a public API on a server with no Access-Control-Allow-Origin - I can try to convince site owner to add it, but how do I do it in the meantime ? I am trying to not run a proxy on my own domain. The data is personal data (electric power consumption), which I want the browser to download and process, and I do not want my server to see the users private API key, which is stored in localStorage only. At some point I want to it to become a true web app.

Fetch with no-cors mode gives me Opaque data, and with cors enabled I get:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.eloverblik.dk/. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)

Any other way to call an API / Get data from a 3rd party site on the web ?

Here is example code:

```
fetch( 'https://www.eloverblik.dk', { method: 'GET', redirect: 'follow'})
.then( (response) => { console.log('x'); console.log('Resp: ' + response.type) })
.then((result) => { console.log('Res: ' + result )})
.catch( (error) => { console.error('Error:', error); })
```

Comment: Use your server as a proxy

Comment: I know you said you don't want to do that, so use some other server that will add cors response headers as a proxy. Is that better than using your own server? Or a Web extension.

Comment: Using a 3rd party server is a no-go. The API key give access to PII data (energy consumption, down to 15m intervals), which criminals would love to get access to, to determine when you are away from home.
I would not want to send my own API key or that of users to anybody but the website

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the help here.

Basically, the answer is, that it is not possible.

The workaround is to use a reverse proxy like nginx and add the header.

I have contacted the site owner and asked them to add the header. It is a public available API, that requires login with an API key you can generate on a website.

They do run another api server, giving anonymous access to public data. That one is run on cloudapp.net. The one where they "forgot" the header has personal electricity consumption measurements - Down to 15m intervals.  It is hosted under t-msedge.net. Hope they will do the change, so I can do away with the proxy.